# Upload file at Wagtail bakerydemo

Tags: django, file-upload, wagtail

I can't make file upload form field work. My references are:

- https://github.com/lb-/bakerydemo/blob/stack-overflow/61289214-wagtail-form-file-upload/bakerydemo/base/models.py
- https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl

The field was added to admin and appear correctly on my site, but when I try to send the form:

- if the field is required, the form is reloaded without any error
- if the field is not required, the form is sent but the file is not uploaded

What am I doing wrong? I've been working on this for 3 days and can't find any error message pointing what's wrong. When I get some error message it's always too generic.

Please help! :)

## My models.py inside bakerydemo/bakerydemo/base

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import json
from os.path import splitext

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
    StreamFieldPanel,
)
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.core.models import Collection, Page
from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormSubmission, AbstractFormField, FORM_FIELD_CHOICES
from wagtail.contrib.forms.views import SubmissionsListView
from wagtail.images import get_image_model
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.images.fields import WagtailImageField
from wagtail.search import index
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

from .blocks import BaseStreamBlock


from django.core.validators import ValidationError





import logging





@register_snippet
class People(index.Indexed, ClusterableModel):
    """
    A Django model to store People objects.
    It uses the `@register_snippet` decorator to allow it to be accessible
    via the Snippets UI (e.g. /admin/snippets/base/people/)

    `People` uses the `ClusterableModel`, which allows the relationship with
    another model to be stored locally to the 'parent' model (e.g. a PageModel)
    until the parent is explicitly saved. This allows the editor to use the
    'Preview' button, to preview the content, without saving the relationships
    to the database.
    https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster
    """
    first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length=254)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=254)
    job_title = models.CharField("Job title", max_length=254)

    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('first_name', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('last_name', classname="col6"),
            ])
        ], "Name"),
        FieldPanel('job_title'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image')
    ]

    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('first_name'),
        index.SearchField('last_name'),
    ]

    @property
    def thumb_image(self):
        # Returns an empty string if there is no profile pic or the rendition
        # file can't be found.
        try:
            return self.image.get_rendition('fill-50x50').img_tag()
        except:  # noqa: E722 FIXME: remove bare 'except:'
            return ''

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = 'People'


@register_snippet
class FooterText(models.Model):
    """
    This provides editable text for the site footer. Again it uses the decorator
    `register_snippet` to allow it to be accessible via the admin. It is made
    accessible on the template via a template tag defined in base/templatetags/
    navigation_tags.py
    """
    body = RichTextField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('body'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Footer text"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Footer Text'


class StandardPage(Page):
    """
    A generic content page. On this demo site we use it for an about page but
    it could be used for any type of page content that only needs a title,
    image, introduction and body field
    """

    introduction = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the page',
        blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.'
    )
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True
    )
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    ]


class GalleryPage(Page):
    """
    This is a page to list locations from the selected Collection. We use a Q
    object to list any Collection created (/admin/collections/) even if they
    contain no items. In this demo we use it for a GalleryPage,
    and is intended to show the extensibility of this aspect of Wagtail
    """

    introduction = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the page',
        blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and '
        '3000px.'
    )
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True
    )
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        Collection,
        limit_choices_to=~models.Q(name__in=['Root']),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text='Select the image collection for this gallery.'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('collection'),
    ]

    # Defining what content type can sit under the parent. Since it's a blank
    # array no subpage can be added
    subpage_types = []


class HomePage(Page):
    """
    The Home Page. This looks slightly more complicated than it is. You can
    see if you visit your site and edit the homepage that it is split between
    a:
    - Hero area
    - Body area
    - A promotional area
    - Moveable featured site sections
    """

    # Hero section of HomePage
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Homepage image'
    )
    hero_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Write an introduction for the bakery'
    )
    hero_cta = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Hero CTA',
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Text to display on Call to Action'
    )
    hero_cta_link = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name='Hero CTA link',
        help_text='Choose a page to link to for the Call to Action'
    )

    # Body section of the HomePage
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Home content block", blank=True
    )

    # Promo section of the HomePage
    promo_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Promo image'
    )
    promo_title = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Title to display above the promo copy'
    )
    promo_text = RichTextField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Write some promotional copy'
    )

    # Featured sections on the HomePage
    # You will see on templates/base/home_page.html that these are treated
    # in different ways, and displayed in different areas of the page.
    # Each list their children items that we access via the children function
    # that we define on the individual Page models e.g. BlogIndexPage
    featured_section_1_title = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Title to display above the promo copy'
    )
    featured_section_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='First featured section for the homepage. Will display up to '
        'three child items.',
        verbose_name='Featured section 1'
    )

    featured_section_2_title = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Title to display above the promo copy'
    )
    featured_section_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Second featured section for the homepage. Will display up to '
        'three child items.',
        verbose_name='Featured section 2'
    )

    featured_section_3_title = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='Title to display above the promo copy'
    )
    featured_section_3 = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Third featured section for the homepage. Will display up to '
        'six child items.',
        verbose_name='Featured section 3'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            ImageChooserPanel('image'),
            FieldPanel('hero_text', classname="full"),
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('hero_cta'),
                PageChooserPanel('hero_cta_link'),
            ]),
        ], heading="Hero section"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            ImageChooserPanel('promo_image'),
            FieldPanel('promo_title'),
            FieldPanel('promo_text'),
        ], heading="Promo section"),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('featured_section_1_title'),
                PageChooserPanel('featured_section_1'),
            ]),
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('featured_section_2_title'),
                PageChooserPanel('featured_section_2'),
            ]),
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('featured_section_3_title'),
                PageChooserPanel('featured_section_3'),
            ]),
        ], heading="Featured homepage sections", classname="collapsible")
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    logging.warning('FormField') 
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='field type',
        max_length=16,
        choices=FORM_FIELD_CHOICES + (('fileupload', 'File Upload'),)
    )


class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):

    logging.warning('CustomFormBuilder') 
    def create_fileupload_field(self, field, options):
        return forms.FileField(**options)


class CustomSubmissionsListView(SubmissionsListView):
    """
    further customisation of submission list can be done here
    """

    logging.warning('CustomSubmissionsListView') 

    pass


class CustomFormSubmission(AbstractFormSubmission):
    # important - adding this custom model will make existing submissions unavailable
    # can be resolved with a custom migration

    def get_data(self):
        """
        Here we hook in to the data representation that the form submission returns
        Note: there is another way to do this with a custom SubmissionsListView
        However, this gives a bit more granular control
        """

        logging.warning('CustomFormSubmission') 

        file_form_fields = [
            field.clean_name for field in self.page.specific.get_form_fields()
            if field.field_type == 'fileupload'
        ]

        data = super().get_data()

        for field_name, field_vale in data.items():
            if field_name in file_form_fields:
                # now we can update the 'representation' of this value
                # we could query the FormUploadedFile based on field_vale (pk)
                # then return the filename etc.
                pass

        return data


def upload_validator(value):
    raise ValidationError(value)
class FormUploadedFile(models.Model):
    logging.warning('FormUploadedFile') 
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/%Y/%m/%d", validators=[upload_validator])
    # file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/%Y/%m/%d")
    field_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    form_builder = CustomFormBuilder
    submissions_list_view_class = CustomSubmissionsListView

    logging.warning('FormPage') 

    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    # body = RichTextField(default="")
    # body = StreamField(BaseStreamBlock())
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True
    )
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    # Note how we include the FormField object via an InlinePanel using the
    # related_name value
    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]

    def get_submission_class(self):
        """
        Returns submission class.
        Important: will make your existing data no longer visible, only needed if you want to customise
        the get_data call on the form submission class, but might come in handy if you do it early

        You can override this method to provide custom submission class.
        Your class must be inherited from AbstractFormSubmission.
        """
        # print('get_submission_class')


        return CustomFormSubmission

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        """
        Accepts form instance with submitted data, user and page.
        Creates submission instance.

        You can override this method if you want to have custom creation logic.
        For example, if you want to save reference to a user.
        """

        # print('process_form_submission')

        file_form_fields = [field.clean_name for field in self.get_form_fields() if field.field_type == 'fileupload']

        for (field_name, field_value) in form.cleaned_data.items():
            if field_name in file_form_fields:
                uploaded_file = FormUploadedFile.objects.create(
                    file=field_value,
                    field_name=field_name
                )

                # store a reference to the pk (as this can be converted to JSON)
                form.cleaned_data[field_name] = uploaded_file.pk

        return self.get_submission_class().objects.create(
            form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            page=self,
        )
```

Comment: Questions and code snippets need to be more specific and concise.   Try to narrow down the code snippet to the minimum possible that still contains and represents your problem.

Comment: I really don't know where is the problem... for this project I will work with Django and in the future will try Wagtail again.